# pushed a commit to origin/master on github, when the git branch is origin/foo

Tags: git, github, magit

I have a branch `foo` in my local git repository.
I made a commit to this `foo`.

I'm using emacs and magit to manage my git repository.
I pushed to my github repo, `origin` but accidentally pushed to `origin/master` rather than `origin/foo`.

**I want to move that commit to `origin/foo`**. Nothing about the local git repository needs to change, as it is correct, it is just the github version that is incorrect.

Comment: How did you push? (exact command)

Comment: m-x g (go to magit)
P u (push origin/master)
However, I believe origin/master had not yet been set on `foo`, and so it prompted me, and I pressed `y` (as in, I said, push upstream to `origin/master`)

Comment: `git push --force origin master && git push origin foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you now have `foo` as remote tracking branch of `origin/master`. You need to fix that to avoid future confusion: `git checkout foo`, then `git push --set-upstream origin foo`.

Then you need to reset `master` on the remote repo. You do this by pushing your local master there. Since that would result in potentially losing data on the remote repo, git will complain. So you need to force it: `git push -f origin master`.